# How to set the floating point symbol in JSpinner to dot instead of comma if the locale is french?

Tags: java, swing, locale, jspinner

I am making a Java application localized in French. I used some `JSpinner`s that accept only a float.

The problem is that the decimal point (the separator between integer part and decimal part) in float numbers is represented by a comma (`,`). This behavior make a number like `12.34` invalid and the `JSpinner` reject it, but If I type `12,34` it will be accepted.

How can I force a `JSpinner` to use a dot (`.`) as the decimal point and not the comma ?

The `main` method begin like this :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRENCH); // Set French as the application language
   /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Okay, when I use `Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRENCH)`, it displays a space instead of `,` or a `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When you use the method `Locale.setDefault(Locale)` it sets the default locale for **display** and also for **formatting**, but in my case, I need only to *display* my user interfaces in French. For that, I have to use also the second overload of the method : `setDefault(Locale.Category, Locale)`, where the first parameter indicate if I want to use the locale for displaying user interfaces or for formatting date, numbers or curencies. The main method now is like this :

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRENCH); // Display the user interfaces in French
Locale.setDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH); // But the formatting in English
```